# Why is the above matrix singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\3&4&5\\5&6&7\end{bmatrix}$$

with $\det(A) = 0$. We know if $\det(A) = 0$, then $A$ is singular. Also, we know if $A$ is singular, columns and rows are linearly dependent. Why are the columns or rows linearly dependent?

Comment: Try bringing the matrix to its reduced row echelon form, from which you can read out linear dependence relation between the columns.

Comment: Do $R_3-R_2$ and then $R_2-R_1$

Comment: Useful trick: Given that the  matrix is singular you can find the coefficients to yield the relationship between the columns: just work out $(1,2,3)\times (3,4,5)$ [This trick works except when the first two rows are multiples of each other.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see that in every row the elements increase by 1 when going from column 1 to column 2 to column 3. In other words:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\6\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\5\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\7\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\6\end{pmatrix}
$$

Rearranging, you will get:
$$
2\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\6\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\5\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\7\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is clearly a linear relation between the columns. Thus, columns are not linearly independent